# Custom circle shape reactive model

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to reach design from screenshot.
All elements in circle must be able to work with logic which include change color.
Gray and green'ish one elements are disabled and blue'ish is active.

Probably I should use some kind of canvas to get this done, but I am not sure.

Thanks for all response!

Edit:
Very important part of logic. I want to dynamicaly change number of those circular elements.

[image: Model]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use custom painter to achieve this.
You can check out [Flutter shape maker](https://shapemaker.web.app/#/)! its a tool that can help with drawing this out.

Comment: This tool seems amazing, but I dont think I could make here few separated elements